# AngularJS ng-repeat manipulate ID

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am looking for an way to easily manipulate an ID within an ng-repeat. For example lets say I have a customer within a customer table with a customerId. I am using that customerId in another table such as orders. Now when I pull the data from orders for a user to see in an ng-repeat table, I would like to change the customerId to customerName for visual purposes only not actually changing the physical value, just the displayed.

My first though, I can see this is possible when requesting a list of orders in the php script to loop request just the customerName based on the customerId from the customer table and add to the orders array, but this seems very long winded and not as friendly as something I could manipulate in the DOM. My second thought was a filter although ajax requests seem to not be viable option within a filter.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers.

Comment: I assume you are loading this from a database? You could join the tables in your SQL query so that it returns both the id and the name.  Also, if you have the customer on the front end in your angular controller, you could just reference that customer object. Without seeing your code, its not really possible to give you more details of how to solve this.

Comment: @mcgraphix I am using mysql so lets say I was looking for an orderId therefore do not know the customerId am I still able to use one query and take the result of the customerId from the first part of the query and use in the last part of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to an "answer" so I can format this better.

Assuming you have two tables. Orders with a foreign key column called CustomerID and Customers table that has a primary key column of CustomerID. You would join them with all the Orders fields you want. I don't have mysql so the syntax could vary slightly but this is the idea:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.SomeField
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName 
WHERE Order.OrderId = 1234;
```

This is directly from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Great so it is possible. Will take a deeper look into this as this is the first time I will join queries :)